# RxJs Marble testing concatMap with withLatestFrom

Tags: testing, rxjs, jasmine-marbles

How can be unit tested this Observable?

```js
e1.pipe(
    concatMap(x => of(x).pipe(withLatestFrom(e2)))
);
```

Following unit test fails:

```js
        it('test', () => {
            const e1 = hot(       '--1^---2----3-|');
            const e2 = hot(       '-a-^-b-----c--|');
            const expected = cold(   '----x----y-|', {
                x: ['2', 'b'],
                y: ['3', 'c']
            });

            const result = e1.pipe(
                concatMap(x => of(x).pipe(
                    withLatestFrom(e2))
                )
            );

            // but this works:
            // const result = e1.pipe(withLatestFrom(e2));

            expect(result).toBeObservable(expected);
        });
```

How the marbles should be written in order to pass this unit test? What did I do wrong?
I expect by inserting `concatMap` operator in the chain (before `withLatestFrom`) I have to also somehow "mark" it in the marbles.

Comment: The test *should* fail. By the time `withLatestFrom` is called, `e2` has already emitted `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your *real* example

```js
e1.pipe(
  concatMap(x => of(x).pipe(withLatestFrom(e2)))
);
```

everything works fine probably because is either a `BehaviorSubject` or a `ReplaySubject`, which it's not case in your test.

Although you're using `hot(       '-a-^-b-----c--|');`, it does not imply that you're using a `BehaviorSubject`. If we look at the [implementation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/15311529fa1b880ed469b6c253cd0be7ff2f98a1/src/internal/testing/HotObservable.ts#L16), we'll see that `HotObservable` extends the `Subject` class:

```js
export class HotObservable<T> extends Subject<T> implements SubscriptionLoggable { /* ... */ }
```

which should help understand why this works:

```js
const result = e1.pipe(withLatestFrom(e2));
```

and this doesn't:

```js
const result = e1.pipe(
    concatMap(x => of(x).pipe(
        withLatestFrom(e2))
    )
);
```

In the first snippet, `e2` is subscribed when `e1` is subscribed. In the second one, because you're using `concatMap`, every time `e1` emits, `withLatestFrom(e2))` will be subscribed and then unsubscribed, due to the `complete` notification that comes from `of(x)`.

With this in mind, here would be my approach:

*Note: I'm using the built-in functions provided by `rxjs/testing`*

```js
it('test', () => {

  // might want to add this in a `beforeEach` function
  let testScheduler = new TestScheduler(
    (actual, expected) => (console.log({actual, expected}),expect(actual).toEqual(expected))
  );

  testScheduler.run(({ hot, expectObservable }) => {
    const e1 = hot(       '--1^---2----3-|');
    const e2src = hot(       '-a-^-b-----c--|');
    const e2 = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);

    const result = e1.pipe(
        concatMap(x => of(x).pipe(
            withLatestFrom(e2))
        )
    );

    const source = merge(
      result,

      e2src.pipe(
        tap(value => e2.next(value)),
        
        // this is important as we're not interesting in `e2src`'s values
        // it's just a way to `feed` the `e2` BehaviorSubject
        ignoreElements()
      )
    );
    
    expectObservable(source).toBe('----x----y-|', {
      x: ['2', 'b'],
      y: ['3', 'c']
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: So it is not that simple as I thought. Basically you used a trick with `merge` to make test start all hot observables at same time. My naive idea was that if I specify some hot observables they will start to emit at same time, or at the time as their marbles describe.

Comment: I’ve got this idea from watching the tests for  the “publishReplay”, so it may be a good source of inspiration